# redirect to asp.net web form deployed on a different machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

net web application running on my home machine.
and i want to talk to a web form running on another machine . in my case i have also a vmware running windows xp which has also a vs2010 and have a web application created..
but when i do 
Response.Redirect("localhost:1206/Default.aspx") from my home machine web application running on vs2010 i dont get the desired page running on the vmware it gives error msg

Note: I also tried the static ip address of my vmware instead of localhost in the URL..

Help plzzzzzzzz

Comment: Just trying to parse what you wrote.  You have 2 machines, both with web apps running.  On machine A you open a browser to the web app on machine A.  The machine A web app does a `Response.Redirect(...)` and you expect what to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Response.Redirect()` in this way, because the `Response` object does not span multiple machines.

You have a few options, at least:

1. Create a web service to expose the logic you have on your other site.
2. Create the fully qualified name of the other application running in the VM and use a hyperlink or anchor with `href` pointing at that location.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a bit of JavaScript on the postback to set

```
window.location = "http://vmserver/page.aspx";
```

If you are not sure how to send JS on the postback, take a look at [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) in MSDN.

This does not allow you to share data between the sites, but you could use query string params to do this.

I would not recommend anything for a production site with sensitive data using only this technique.